# Bootstrap data-toggle collapses div after second click, not first

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I have the [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfpcxg0r/) with Bootstrap and toggling divs by click. Here is markup:

```
<div class="accordion-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle"
       data-toggle="collapse"
       data-parent="#accordion2"
       href="#collapseOne">Open!</a>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="well well-small">
            <div class="accordion-toggle">
                ...some text...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span2"></div>                            
</div>
```

When user clixks link with title 'Open!' underlying div expands or collapses. Div is expanded initially and when user clicks first time it has no effect. Then if user clicks second time, div collapses.

In the [original example](http://jsfiddle.net/cg8E3/) div is collapsed initially but I would like it  to be opened. How could I fix the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add class 'collaspe in' to class="accordion-body".

Check example code at [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/rrNJOP)

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle"
       data-toggle="collapse"
       data-parent="#accordion2"
       href="#collapseOne">Open!</a>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="well well-small">
            <div class="accordion-toggle">
                ...some text...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span2"></div>                            
</div>
```

I hope this will fix your issue.
Enjoy :)

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, and in my case I had foolishly inserted two "class" attributes in the div I wanted to collapse like so:

```
<div class="something" id="mydiv" class="collapse in"> <div>
```

The browser seems to eliminate the second class attribute instead of merging them.

My problem was fixed by "merging" together the two class attributes:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="something collapse in"> <div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsePanel" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsePanel">Collapse</a>

<div id="collapsePanel" class="collapse show"><!-- Content Here --></div>
```

This will make it collapsible, but show the panel by default. When you click the Collapse button, it will collapse the panel on the first click.

I'm only adding this here for if anyone is looking to do it either way. I found this link when searching for its inverse. Hope it helps!

Comment: Just adding "show" to the collapsible element classes worked for me. I guess it initializes the state of the element so that it doesn't have to initialize on the first event.

Answer (score 3):

You should only call `bootstrap.min.js` one. Make sure that you're calling bootstrap files only once in the `<head>` section.
If you're using Bootstrap with Laravel or any kind of framework, keep in mind that `npm run dev` compiles bootstrap js files in `app.js`. That could be the case.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
```

This will also make it close by default and open when clicked

Answer (score 2):

If anyone interested why this happens, probably you didn't add "collapse" class to element that you want to collapse. If you want to show the collapse element by default you can add "collapse show". If you dont add collapse your data-bs-toggle="collapse" attirbute cant find a "collapse" class to toggle on your target element. So when you first click to target element bootstrap adds collapse and show to that div. Thats causes you to see its collapsing and showing afterwards you clicked for first time. 
**if you want to hide target element by default add to target element "collapse"** 
**if you want to show the target element but want it to be collapse when clicked add "collapse show" to target element** 
bootstrap will do everything for you afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. Set id and data-bs-parent