# Bootstrap 4 collapse working only with the second click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having the same issue of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290431/bootstrap-data-toggle-collapses-div-after-second-click-not-first) question but with bootstrap 4. I want to use [collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) feature, with the content shown by default. The problem is that the content does not hide with the first click, only with the second. The issue is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w6r0kuj5/):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
</button>

<div class="collapse.show in" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `show` class in the `collapse` not `collapse.show` - All the rest of your `code` is perfectly fine!

**Live Demo:**

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>

<div class="collapse show" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Why does the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) says "collapse.show" an not "collapse show"?!

Comment: @Miguel Correct! It only `collapse` initially you just want to add `show` to make it visible always and one the click event trigger it will remove show from collapse.